# How to Join GetStream Feed Group?

Tags: getstream-io

Could you tell me how to join specific feed group in [getstream](https://getstream.io/)

When I try to get the feeds, it says, 'no permission'. I think user is not joined to feed group, so this error occurs,

But unfortunately, I cannot find the code join to feedGroup from the [docs](https://getstream.io/docs/js/)

Comment: it is not very clear what "join" means, can you add the code you are using and/or add more information on your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the activities in another feed, the logical concept is `follow`. You can follow the interesting feed and its activities will be copied to your feed.

You can find the details in [follow docs](https://getstream.io/docs/#following).

Additionally, different permissions can be given for more interesting use-cases such as looking at a profile of somebody without actually following the user (i.e. the feed). Then, you can contact the [support](https://getstream.io/support) to get it done.